# Is SNMP++ worth using

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I have implemented a small program which uses Net-SNMP to get network related information. It uses asynchronous mode to query multiple hosts.

Since Net-SNMPv3 does not support multi-threading, is it beneficial to shift to SNMP++?
I have a lot of hosts or routers in the network where I need to monitor the traps and general network information of ~2000 routers.

Will using SNMP++ be much faster that Net-SNMP as it uses multi-threading?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are implementing in C++ and maybe need to, but I you can use snmp4j it has the possibility to use multi-threading. Even if you have to wrap the code to using Java.
Are at the same issue, where 1-2000 units need both SNMP Get / Walks and due to slow units, there needs to be multiple threads fetching data in parallel.